# How do I stop getting EAP updates in PhpStorm 8?

Tags: settings, phpstorm, updates

I used to experiment with EAP versions of PhpStorm.

Now I want to stick with the latest stable version, but I still get update notifications for the EAP.

How can I disable this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `Settings | Updates` for v8.0.1 and older
- `Settings | Appearance & Behaviour | System Settings | Updates` for v8.0.2 and newer
- .. or just use search box and search for "updates" in `Settings` screen or `Search Everywhere` functionality

Once there -- change `updates channel` to a desired one.

**NOTE:** "Settings" is for Windows/Linux; on Mac it's called "Preferences".